# Create from Vector Tiles a custom svg section

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, svg

I'm planing to enclude some mapping features to my wordpress website . Therefore I'm asking you whether my plan makes sense and is practical. And also how much a freelancer would cost (one payment).

[image: enter image description her]

1. I created this style.json above with Mapbox to style my Vector Tiles.
2. The style.json should be applied on the [OSM2VectorTiles](http://osm2vectortiles.org/downloads/) download. Then somone need to help me by installing them on my A2 Hosting.
3. Most complicated would be probably a custom wordpress plugin which create from the Vector Tiles a svg (like on the openstreetmap hompage - just with custom styles). I want to use this svg maps in the Mapplic Plugin (probably).